# How to debug code in android studio with all the classes which we have used in the project?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I have a simple question related to the How Debug code in android studio, suppose  I have  two classes in my application fist one is `MainActivity.java` and second one is  `SunshineSyncAdapter.java` that contain method `initializeSyncAdapter()`.

I am accessing `SunshineSyncAdapter` class  that contains method `initializeSyncAdapter()` in my `MainActivity.java` class. My question is that I wanted, my debugger/cursor in `SunshineSyncAdapter.java` class so that I can get what is happening their, debugger is not redirect to the second class code is like this in `MainActivty.java class`.

```
SunshineSyncAdapter.initializeSyncAdapter(this);
```

Comment: Set breakpoint in initializeSyncAdapter? Or use Debug Step Into instead of Debug Step Over

Comment: From Debugger setting>stepping>AddPattern, i have added to android.*; to avoid the debugging of system classes.

Comment: I have already set the break point but still its not redirecting and step over click its stuck, after pressing two , three times its show  directly o/p on Emulator.

Comment: thanks, for valuable reply@Rvdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First decide values of which variables matter to you. Find those lines in the code in studio and then put breakpoint there . Now if your application is already running , find attach debugger option in menu at the top and attach debugger to the process you want and you can use watch , evaluate expression etc. If you run application in debug mode then also you will be able to debug the application. Use step over , step into , step out etc as usual which are at bottom left in android studio.

[image: Run you app and debug you process by attaching debugger , see image for reference.]

Comment: thanks, I got  second part of your ans. that solve my problem but in the first part how to attach debugger while app  is running will you please explain it.@Kris.

Comment: I have edited answer with reference image. Please see if it helps,.

Comment: Thanks , I got it.@Kris.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your code same as debugging in eclipse.

You need to add break points where you want to break code and then

1.Launch project in debugging mode.

2.If you want to debug on run time :: attach debugger to running process by click on button left to settings.